# Can we define a special measure in this way?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

My question comes from a paper and I have no concrete background on this.

Let $\mu$ be an probability measure over $(X,M(X))$, where $M(X)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $X.$  So $\mu$ is nonnegative. $f(x): X\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, excluding $\pm\infty$.

Consider the following:   $$\int_X f(x) d\mu(x) = \int_X d\big(\nu^+(x)-\nu^-(x)\big) =\int_X d\nu^+(x)-\int_Xd\nu^-(x)$$

where $\nu^+$, $\nu^-\in\mathcal{M}(X)$ are nonnegative measures. $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is a vector space of measures on $X$.

LHS is just a normal integration; however, RHS becomes the algebraic computation of unsigned measures. It  seems to me that we can create a signed measure $\nu^+-\nu^-$ by including $f(x)$, which is a real number, into $d\mu(x)$.

My questions are

1. Now $\nu^+$, $\nu^-$ are not probability measure and not nonnegative but are still measures?
2. This new measure encodes the information of $f(x)$?
3. Are there any other examples or applications of such technique?

Comment: Are $\nu^\pm$ given measures satisfying the first equality or are they defined by the first equality? What are $\sigma^\pm$ in the expression $\sigma^+ - \sigma^-$? Are they supposed to be $\nu^\pm$?

Comment: @md2perpe  1. I think it should be "defined"   2. Sorry for the typos, it should be $\nu^+-\nu^-$

Comment: @md2perpe That equality comes from the following paper, equation (23): https://groups.csail.mit.edu/robotics-center/public_papers/Majumdar14.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu$ is a measure (non-negative, but not necessarily finite), and $f \in L^1(\mu)$, then $\nu(A) := \int_A f \, d\mu$ defines a signed measure. By the [Hahn decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem) this can be decomposed into two non-negative mutually singular measures in a unique way, $\nu = \nu^+ - \nu^-$.

1. If $\mu$ is a probability measure, i.e. $\mu(X)=1,$ then $\nu^\pm$ are not necessarily probability measures.
2. $\nu$ or $\{\nu^+, \nu^-\}$ encodes the information of $f$ almost everywhere. If $f$ changes on a $\mu$-null set, then $\nu$ will not change.

Comment: I get it, thanks!